# Can I create an Azure VM from Ansible with NICs in different resource groups?

Tags: ansible, azure

I am working on creating an Ansible playbook to

- Ensure required network resources for an Azure VM are present, and
- Create an Azure VM attached to those resources.

Due to the way the organization is structured, all *network resources* (such as NIC, NSG, Subnets and Public IPs) are placed in a `Networks` Resource Group in Azure. And these are managed by a separate team.

Also, the mandate is to create the Azure VMs and all *non network* resources in a separate resource group (let's call it `AZRVMRG`.

The chunk of the playbook that creates the VM looks like this:

```
---
- name: "Create VM {{vm_type}} - {{name}}"
  azure_rm_virtualmachine:
    resource_group: "{{rg_name}}"
    name: "{{name}}"
    vm_size: "{{size}}"
    admin_username: "{{user}}"
    admin_password: "{{pass}}"
    os_type: "{{os_type}}"
    network_interfaces: "{{nic_name}}"
    image: "{{image}}"
    tags: "{{tags}}"
```

Where `{{rg_name}}` is the `AZRVMRG` RG, and `{{nic_name}}` is an existing NIC present in the `Networks` RG.

### Question

How do I reference the NIC present in the `Networks` resource group while creating the Azure VM within `AZRVMRG` resource group?

### What I've tried

I have tried "just" referencing the NIC name, but that gives me an error similar to:

```
 "msg": "Error fetching network interface AZRVMNIC - Azure Error: ResourceNotFound\nMessage: The Resource 'Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/AZRVMNIC' under resource group 'AZRVMRG' was not found."
```

So clearly, its looking under the same resource group.

### Notes

(I have seen VMs created in the Azure subscription this way, so this is possible in Azure. But Ansible does not document this approach in its [official docs.](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/azure_rm_virtualmachine_module.html) )

Answer (score 1):

From close reading of the [Ansible doc page](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/azure_rm_virtualmachine_module.html) on creating Azure VMs, it's clear that you can refer to a resource such as a virtual network or NIC using its resource ID.  This lets you specify any resource, just like RM templates.

To specify a NIC created in another resource group by the networking team, with the `networking_rg_name` var set to that group name, you would use a resource ID like this:

```
- set_fact:
    nic_id: "/subscriptions/{{ subscription_id }}/resourceGroups/{{ networking_rg_name }}/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/{{ nic_name }}"

- name: "Create VM {{vm_type}} - {{name}}"
  azure_rm_virtualmachine:
    resource_group: "{{rg_name}}"
    name: "{{name}}"
    vm_size: "{{size}}"
    admin_username: "{{user}}"
    admin_password: "{{pass}}"
    os_type: "{{os_type}}"
    network_interfaces: "{{nic_id}}"     # Use the nic_id instead of name
    image: "{{image}}"
    tags: "{{tags}}"
```

This works for any resources that are in a different resource group, including virtual networks.